# How Can I send selected text to controller from DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to send the selected text field in dropdown to the controller.
When I use the code as follows, I can send the id number to the controllers, but the value I selected in the list pass null.

In addition , if there is a registered value in the model, I want this field to be selected in the dropdownlist when the page is opened.

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Degerlendir(int id ,string CV_STATU)
        {
        using (MULAKATDBEntities1 ent = new MULAKATDBEntities1())
                    {
                        CvViewModel cv = new CvViewModel();
                        var entData = ent.CV.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID_CV == id);
                        entData.CV_STATU = CV_STATU;
                        ent.SaveChanges();
                     } 
        }
```

In View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Degerlendir", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.Cv.ID_CV" />
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cv.CV_STATU,
            new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Secilmedi" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Kabul edildi" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Reddedildi" } },
            new {@id="cv_statu", @class = "form-control" })
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="KAYDET" class="btn btn-add" />
 }
```

Comment: You could always pass ````FormCollection formC```` in as a parameter and then you could loop through the collection to find the control (i.e. dropdown list) that you wanted to get the value.  This can be helpful if you have many controls inside the form action.

Answer (score 1):

Set `@name="cv_statu"` within the HTML helper htmlAttributes for binding to parameters on POST like this.

Also change the controller method parameter to lowercase `cv_statu`. Only parameter names passed through URL routes are not case sensitive.

Comment: Can you post the html of what the generated element looks like?

Comment: Also added comment about change the parameter to be lowercase to match the post back.

Comment: I changed code like that : In controller :                                                                   public ActionResult Degerlendir(int id ,string cv_statu)                                           view :   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cv.CV_STATU,
            new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Secilmedi" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Kabul edildi" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Reddedildi" } },
            new {@id="cv_statu", @class = "form-control", @name="cv_statu" })

Comment: Make sure you have restarted the application if you make controller changes while debugging. If it is still not working then you will need to add to your question what the generated html for that element looks like so we can see exactly what you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that what you shared on your code for your `ActionResult` is already the `HttpPost` Action verb. There should be a proper `HttpGet` as well.

To solve your issue, make sure the first argument that you set on your DropDownListFor should match on the parameter of your `Degerlendir`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CV_STATU,
        new List<SelectListItem> {
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Secilmedi", Value = "Secilmedi" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Kabul edildi", Value = "Secilmedi" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Reddedildi", Value = "Reddedildi", Selected = true} }, "Please select an option",
        new {@id="cv_statu", @class = "form-control" })
```

As you notice, I changed your:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cv.CV_STATU
```

To:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CV_STATU
```

Because what you set here will set the `name` attribute on your HTML. This will be binded on your parameter on your `ActionResult` of `Degerlendir` particularly your parameter:

```
string CV_STATU
```

Lastly, I added `Value` on your `SelectListItem`, because that will be passed on your ActionResult whatever you select on your DropDownList. To set the default selected value, just add `Selected = true`.

Comment: Without knowing anything more about the model, I'm assuming `CV_STATU` is not a property of the model directly but is a property of a property. I'm assuming this won't compile.

Comment: On the OP post, it was nested, that's why I simplified it so that it shouldn't be Cv.CV_STATU but rather CV_STATU

Comment: CV_STATU is not a property of the model directly so I do not compile.I changed selectlist to selection and option then it's worked.But ı have any idea , what was the problem for selectlist item .